# View cellular signal of iPhone on Mac

Tags: macos, iphone, tethering, signal-strength

when I'm using tethering with my iPhone, is there any way to see the cellular signal strength on my mac?

Any free solutions are still welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, download [TetherStrength](https://itunes.apple.com/app/tether-strength/id685197013) (Mac App Store link).

Comment: Is it available somewhere this time?